# Continuous read of USB attached device using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, usb, listener

Right now we have a Windows app that continuously reads a USB-attached scale and displays (and uses) the value.

Can I do this via a web page?  Someone mentioned a "javascript input event listener", maybe?  Does anyone have a simple HTML example?

thanks

Comment: only chrome packaged apps have such an API, at least that i've come across. luckily, those are simple to install locally and still just html/css/js, just with one extra json file. win8 might have an API as well.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you would be able to get information from hardware using a browser without using a java applet or something similar.

You could write a web interface that communicates with a process running on the machine, but you would not be able to access the hardware directly through the browser.

For more information regarding the protections surrounding browsers, look here:

http://www.australianscience.com.au/research/google/35779.pdf

My suggestion:

If you have a windows application but you want to run the interface in the browser, do something like VLC (http://www.howtogeek.com/117261/how-to-activate-vlcs-web-interface-control-vlc-from-a-browser-use-any-smartphone-as-a-remote/)